# What to do when the ROIs are smaller than $227 \times 227$ in R-CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, object-detection, r-cnn

As English is not my native language, I have some hard time understanding the following sentence:

> Regardless of the size or aspect ratio of the candidate region, we warp all pixels in a tight bounding box around it to the required size. Prior to warping, we dilate the tight bounding box so that at the warped size there are exactly p pixels of warped image context around the original box (we use p = 16).

This is from [the R-CNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2524.pdf#page=3). I already extracted the ROI, but now, they say that the input of the CNN should be 227 x 227, but a lot of my ROIs are much smaller. How can I deal with it?

Comment: Hello. I am still not sure if your question was theoretical/conceptual or practical (programming issue), but I would like to note that programming issues are generally off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually very easy, I didn't know the solution would be that simple.
With opencv, you can do :

```
resized_roi= cv2.resize(roi, (224,224))
```

and that's it :]